# wordpress query_post trouble

Tags: php, wordpress, categories

how can I extend this query to multiple categories and not just one? or even better how can I make this query to filter categories by ID instead of slug?

```
query_posts( array( 'category' => 'games', 'posts_per_page' => -1 ) );
```

Comment: Hi, always do remember to Google first! A query for `wordpress query_posts multiple categories` should give you all the pointers you need. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
query_posts(array('cat' => '1,2,3,4', 'posts_per_page' => -1));
```

But you should use `WP_Query` instead.

```
$args = array(
   'cat' => '1,2,3,5',
   'posts_per_page' => -1
);
$posts = new WP_Query($args):
//check if it has posts
if($posts->have_posts()){
    //loop through the post
    while($posts->have_posts()){
        $posts->the_post();
        echo the_title();
        echo the_content();
   }
}else{
    echo 'No posts found';
}
```